# Add a image to RadioButton in a ListBox

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc, toolkit

I have a List Box hwich is modified in a such a way that each row will have Radiobutton .Now my requirement is each of these Radio button must have a bitmap image followed by some text . i have codejock xtremetoolkit 13.4.0 installed . I am new to UI design and xtreme toolkit.Can any one help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make the listbox owner drawn and then overload the WM_PAINT message for Radiobutton so that the picture and text can be painted. For more information on owner drawn list box see this link: [CListBox::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc9hahtd%28VS.80%29.aspx)

For more information on owner drawn button see this link: [CButton::DrawItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0k9f0a4%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!